# Measure FLOPs from Numpy operations

Tags: python, numpy, profiling, flops

Is there a general way of measuring how many floating-point operations a sequence of Numpy commands involves?—commands such as `np.random.randint`, `np.sum`, `np.argmin`, `np.matmul` or `@`, etc.

Or is the only way to do it manually, thinking from a pure mathematical standpoint and/or looking at how Numpy implements the functions, as follows:

- matrix multiplication involves (2p - 1)mn FLOPs, if we multiply a m × p matrix by a p × n matrix
- argmin involves O(n) ≈ cn comparisons for an array of length n, but what should c be? I tried looking at the [Numpy source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.18.4/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1193-L1267) but I'm fairly confused about how `_wrapfunc` is supposed to work or what C code is relevant here.
- etc.

Comment: What's the point? The flops is only part of the computation - code interpretaion, function calling, making objects (array and otherwise), memory allocation, copying buffers, garbage collection all affect the total time.

Comment: Those are some good points. It's to compare performance to a paper that measures performance in number of floating-point operations, and it's a measure that would be more transferable across computers, compared to directly measuring time.

Comment: My answer to this `O` question might be relevant, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52201990/901925